# How can I get and store a selected geom feature to use in other functions in my Azure Maps app

Tags: javascript, geometry, maps, azure-maps

I am using a 'click' event on features in a map. I am using a "global" var that I should be able to reuse but when I try using the var again it reports var is 'undefined'. I've been unable to figure what or why this is getting set to 'undefined' so wondering if there's any way to store the say the ID of the geom feature that I can then simply "hide" on the web page and then retrieve that value again to select the feature without needing to click feature again?

```
// Global vars
var map, shp;

// Called by click event
function getFeatureProps (e) {
 shp = e; // store selected feature (e) for use later
 ...do other things...
  alert(shp); // reports [object] as expected
}

// Called from button
function changeFeatureProperties () {
    if (shp.shapes[0].getType() == 'Polygon') {   // ERROR: shp is undefined
       ...only if Polygon...
    }
    else if (shp.shapes[0].getType() == 'Point') {
       ...only if Point...
    }
    ...do other things...
}
```

TIA!

Rick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for delay I've been dealing with pandemic issues!

I tried many different ideas and this is the only one that worked consistently for me.

So I corrected storage as such

```
// Upon object onclick function:
sessionStorage.setItem('shape', JSON.stringify(e.shapes[0].toJson()));

    To retrieve if required after storage
    getTheProps(shape);


    function getTheProps(e) {
        var properties;

        if (e instanceof atlas.Shape) {
            alert('Atlas is Shape');
            properties = e.shapes[0].getProperties();
            pos = e.position;
        }
        else {
            alert('Atlas is Geometry');
            properties = e.properties;
            pos = e.geometry.position;
        }
    }
```

So this worked out for me as desired and hopefully will help others if they have this requirement.

Cheers!
Rick...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the only reason I can think of shp being undefined is that the changeFeatureProperties is called before getFeatureProps, or that getFeatureProps is being called when no shape has been clicked. Is the event on the map or on a layer?

ID's can be used and shapes stored in a DataSource can be retrieved by ID using the getShapeById function.

Also worth noting, the shapes returned by events can be an atlas.Shape or a GeoJSON feature object. If the shape was added to a DataSource, an atlas.Shape object will be returned, in most other cases it will be a GeoJSON feature. To handle this, add an if statement like

```
if(e.shapes[0] instanceof atlas.Shape){
   if(e.shapes[0].getType() === 'Polygon'){
      ...
   }
} else {
   //Shape is a GeoJSON feature.
   if(e.shapes[0].geometry.type === 'Polygon'){
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. No the click event is happening first onclick (on the layer) the changeFeatureProps can only be called from button that is not enabled unless feature is selected. I am trying to now simply ensure object is available by using sessionStorage like so:
    sessionStorage.setItem('shape', JSON.stringify(e.shapes[0].toJson()));
    shape = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shape'));
    alert('Shape: ' + shape); // valid [object Object] returned 
    alert('Shape Type: ' + shape.shapes[0].getType());  // shapes is undefined

Thanks again.

Comment: I've got the storage mechanism figured out. However I am also trying to add your "testing" code and I get an error
if (e.shapes[0] instanceof atlas.Shape) {
 ....
}
I get an error that atlas is not defined?

What am I missing here?

Comment: If atlas is not defined, that means the Azure Maps web SDK isn't loaded yet.

Comment: @Rick, if the above suggestions helped, please mark the response as answer for the benifit of the community